# Palindrome Program

Tags: java, palindrome

I'm trying to write a program which will output what Palindromes will work from entering in a string and how many there are. I keep getting a lot of errors and I'm still trying to get my head around some of the harder topics in Java!

Here's what I have already, as always, all answers are greatly appreciated!

```
public static boolean Palindrome(String text) {
    int index;
    int palindrome;

    System.out.println("Please enter your text ");
    text = EasyIn.getString();
    for(index = 0; index < amount.length() / 2; index++) {
        if(text.charAt(index) != text.charAt(text.length() - index - 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number of valid palindrome(s) is " + amount);
    amount = EasyIn.getString();
}
```

Comment: "_I keep getting a lot of errors_" And what errors would they be?

Comment: 1) Does this have anything to do with jaas? 2) We can't really help you if you don't tell us what errors you are getting.

Comment: Can you explain which errors you are getting?  Additionally, can you explain what you mean by "how many palindromes will work"?

Comment: The errors I'm getting seem to be from my last line of code. Asking for an identifier and adding a " ; " when theres already one there ?

Comment: It's because you aren't running it in a main method, it appears to just be floating out there.

Comment: I want it to outprint how many palindromes there are as in figure wise aswell as telling me which ones are valid palindromes

Comment: Also, what is amount? You never show a declaration or assignment, but use it twice.

Comment: I just noticed that I never declared 'amount' as anything. I've now taken it out and used 'text'

Comment: I believe that there are 2 requirements. The first part is to check if a text is a palindrome. The next part is that with a given list of strings, how many are valid palindromes.

Comment: Yes thats basically what I'm trying to achive Chris. I understand that I messed up on explaining it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is in `amount.length()`, you should use `text.length()`, since you are looping over the half of `text`. The algorithm works fine. Here is a reduced example:

```
public static boolean palindrome(String text)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < text.length() / 2; index++) {
        if (text.charAt(index) != text.charAt(text.length() - index - 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Note:**

- You forgot to add a `return true` statement, if you don't add one, is possible that the `for` loop finishes and no `return` statement is reached, which will cause an error.
- I would recommend you to follow Java naming conventions. You method should be called like `someMethodName` instead of `SomeMethodName`. This last is used for class names.

**Edit:**
As @bobbel commented, you could improve this code by assigning `text.length()` to a variable and using it inside the `for`.

Comment: This is a great solution! However, pull out the `text.length()` calls to a variable, so it won't be called two times a loop. This will improve the code! Furthermore: why aren't you defining your `index` variable inside the for loop: `for (int index; ....)`

Comment: @bobbel I just revised the algorithm, but overlooked the implementation details. Thanks for pointing it out. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two things:

ammount variable that you used either it could be a string array that you are maintaining strings inside it, if this is the case than you have to loop first through array of strings and then maintain one nested loop to check that strings inside it are palindrom or not

or second case is that you have used the variable incorrect it may be text instead of ammount

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter string to check for palidrome");
    String orginal = in.next();

    int start = 0;
    int middle = orginal.length()/2;
    int end = orginal.length() - 1;
    int i;

    for(i=start; i<=middle; i++) {
        if(orginal.charAt(start) == orginal.charAt(end)) {
            start++;
            end--;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if(i == middle+1) {
        System.out.println("palidrome");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not palidrome");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Simplest way of Checking **Palindrom number**.

```
package testapi;

public class PalindromNumber {

    public static void checkPalindrom(Object number) {
        StringBuilder strNumber = new StringBuilder(number.toString());
        String reverseNumber = strNumber.reverse().toString();
        if (number.toString().equals(reverseNumber)) {
            System.out.println(number + " is palindrom number");
        } else {
            System.out.println(number + " is not palindrom number");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        checkPalindrom(101);
        checkPalindrom(10.01);
        checkPalindrom("aanaa");
    }

}
```